# Loop over multiple character columns to derive a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Could you please help me with a code in R. I want to derive a new variable available with values as Yes or No, however it need to check the character variables a1, a2, a3, a4 and whichever variable has a value as 'yellow' then available variable should be yes else no.

```
a1 <- c('orange','red') 
a2 <- c('red','yellow') 
a3 <- c('black','orange') 
a4 <- c('red','brown')

testa <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4)
```

[image: I want the available variable as below]

Comment: Your instructions and expected output are contradictory. Do you expect "yes" when there is "yellow" in the rows, or do you expect "no"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### dplyr

You may use `rowwise` and `c_across`:

```r
testa %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(available = ifelse(any(c_across(a1:a4) == "yellow"), "yes", "no"))

  a1     a2     a3     a4    available
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    
1 orange red    black  red   no       
2 red    yellow orange brown yes
```

#### base R

Use `apply`:

```r
testa$available <- apply(testa, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x == "yellow"), "yes", "no"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
a1 <- c('orange','red') 
a2 <- c('red','yellow') 
a3 <- c('black','orange') 
a4 <- c('red','brown')

df <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(available = ifelse(rowSums(. == "yellow") > 0, "yes", "no"))
#>       a1     a2     a3    a4 available
#> 1 orange    red  black   red        no
#> 2    red yellow orange brown       yes

library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, available := ifelse(rowSums(.SD == "yellow") > 0, "yes", "no")][]
#>        a1     a2     a3    a4 available
#> 1: orange    red  black   red        no
#> 2:    red yellow orange brown       yes
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could just concatenate the cells in each row and look for the character `"yellow"` in the resulting strings:

```
> grepl("yellow",paste(as.data.frame(t(testa))))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

You can then use this resulting logical vector to put labels in a new column:

```
testa$available = c("no","yes")[grepl("yellow",paste(as.data.frame(t(testa))))+1]
```

That would result in the data.frame:

```
> testa
      a1     a2     a3    a4 available
1 orange    red  black   red        no
2    red yellow orange brown       yes
```

(If you want `"yes"` for the lines that do not contain yellow, just flip them in the vector `c("no","yes")`)